# TCL version conflict with bltwish

Tags: tcl

I am installing blt2.4z onto my desktop to use with an older plotting tool and am having trouble getting bltwish to run without throwing an "application-specific initialization failed: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.10, need exactly 8.6" error.

To save some trouble I will admit that I know blt2.4z is old and not stated to work with tcl8.5 or tcl8.6, BUT through some workarounds I have gotten the configure script to run with no errors and it to compile and build. The problem arises when I try to run a demo and it gives the error above. The error seems odd to me because TCL should know the difference between its version and patch level, so maybe it comes from confusion within bltwish confusing the two.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, and for reference I downloaded tcl/tk packages through APT so everything is in the standard places.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details of the workarounds you applied to get the software to build

Comment: An alternative: the Tcl source [is on github](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl), so you could clone it and checkout the release tag that works with blt.